# Sync: how get a blob from MySql and save it in another MySql with php

Tags: php, mysql, blob, blobstorage

First of all, Im sorry for my bad English, and thank you all for view my cuestion.

I want to sync two Mysql, but I can't get it work with blob types.

The two connections are equal in username and password.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die();
mysqli_select_db($conn, DB_NAME) or die();
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8') or die();

// db connection string variables
$connEco = mysqli_connect("192.168.20.2", DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die();
mysqli_select_db($connEco, DB_NAME) or die();
mysqli_set_charset($connEco, 'utf8') or die();
$sql="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users_in_fmd";
$rs = mysqli_query($connEco, $sql)
or die(mysqli_error($connEco));

$sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_in_fmd` ( `UsersInFmd` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `SucursalId` int(10) NOT NULL, `UserId` int(10) NOT NULL, `FMD` mediumblob, `FingerIndex` int(2) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`UsersInFmd`), KEY `UserId` (`UserId`)) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0";

$rs = mysqli_query($connEco, $sql)
or die("Error 1");

$sql="SELECT UsersInFmd, SucursalId, UserId, FMD, FingerIndex FROM users_in_fmd";
$rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
or die("Error 2");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
{
    //The row['FMD'] is the data.
    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO users_in_fmd (`UsersInFmd`, `SucursalId`, `UserId`, `FMD`, `FingerIndex`) VALUES ('".$row['UsersInFmd']."', '".$row['SucursalId']."', '".$row['UserId']."', '".$row['FMD']."', '".$row['FingerIndex']."')";
    $updateregistro = mysqli_query($connEco,$sql3) or die("Error 3");
}
```

I have try to get the FMD data in HEX() from mysql, I have try to UNHEX() when is inserted, but all is the same result, I cant import the blob data into the MySql database.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: What error(s) are you getting? What part is not working.

Comment: The error is You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ZVE??c???????
\9;???/??"(??!B?{??Fb?c??"??D,⬆?i?k?G*a

I try with HEX(FMD), FingerIndex..... but when I upload the data is corrupted.

Comment: It was a bad idea to save it as a blob in the first place. Now if you are geting it out of there, save it as a file. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38829952/267540

Comment: Hi, thank you for your Answers, I make a workarround, I solved making a dump file and then uploading to the other server, the option that it work for dumping the Blob was the option --hex-blob (mysqldump  -h $SERVER_IP -u"$USER" -p"$DB_PASS" --hex-blob $table > $file)

Answer (score 0):

Try [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of building your query manually like that.

The error you are getting suggests that the blob needs to be escaped properly.

Comment: Yes, you know how to do that ? I have been try HEX() for select and UNHEX() for insert, but I get a 0 kb blob in the copy database file.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your Answers, I make a workarround, I solved making a dump file and then uploading to the other server, the option that it work for dumping the Blob was the option --hex-blob (mysqldump -h $SERVER_IP -u"$USER" -p"$DB_PASS" --hex-blob $table > $file)